# document type does not allow element "style" here?

Tags: html, css, w3c-validation

Is it possible to pass validation our html in w3 by giving style inside our template page.
I am using zend. In my template phtml file i am having styles like

```
<style type="text/css">
    .re_mid li{
         list-style: none outside none;
}
</style>
```

So this fails in validation saying "`document type does not allow element "style" here`"  which means , we should write our style inside `<HEAD>` tag
Is it possible to pass validation even if i add style inside `<BODY>` tag,
Like we use  `<script>//<![CDATA[ .... //]]></script>`

Comment: @james actually, i am doing shopping cart site which is having more template page. Every page is having styles i said.How can i handle here ? Kindly advice on this.

Comment: If all pages have the same styles, why not put them in an external file and include that in the `head` of each page?

Answer (score 4):

No. The [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#h-14.2.3) states:

> The STYLE element allows authors to put style sheet rules in the head
>   of the document. HTML permits any number of STYLE elements in the HEAD
>   section of a document.

The same is true of the `link` element if you were trying to include an external stylesheet.

If you want to use the `style` element, you'll have to put it in the `head`. If you need to define styles within the `body` your best bet is probably to use inline styles.

Comment: Thanks james, i am using   like <?=  $this->headLink()
                ->appendStylesheet(BASE_URL . 'css/mypage.css');  ?> in template page.this will write css inside <HEAD> tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use in-line styles within the `<body></body>` section but you are defining a document wide style so that needs to be inside the `<head></head>` section.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML spec specifically states style elements are to be placed inside the head. So, no, you cannot place it inside the body and still validate.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to pass validation using jQuery because I could insert style only inside template file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
//<![CDATA[
var style = jQuery('<style type="text/css">'+<?php echo json_encode($style); ?>+'</style>');
jQuery('html > head').append(mb_popup_style);
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can now add the `scope` attribute to the style tag to get it to validate, e.g.

```
<style scope>
.re_mid li{
     list-style: none outside none;
}
</style>
```